# Missing template error on RSPEC testing controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following error when I'm testing my controller. Follow the code... My template is created and is working... this is loaded on a modal via ajax request... (:

```
1) UserManagementController GET #new returns http success
     Failure/Error: render layout: false     
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template user_management/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:pt], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
         * "/home/euax/Documentos/RailsProjects/artia-app/app/views"
         * "/home/euax/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@artia/gems/devise-4.3.0/app/views"
         * "/home/euax/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3@artia/gems/ckeditor-4.2.3/app/views"
```

Follow the code....

**Rspec**

```
it "returns http success" do
   sign_in @administrator_one
   get :new, params: { organization_id: @organization_one.id, "community_id" => "administration" }

   expect(response.status).to eql(200)
end
```

**Controller**

```
    def new
      if administrator? || can_manage_account_permission?(params[:community_id].to_i)
      @accounts = @organization.communities
      @user = OrganizationUser.new(other: true)
      @community_id = params[:community_id].to_i unless params[:community_id] == "administration"

      render layout: false

    else
      response.status = 403
      render json: { message: I18n.t('error_permission') }
    end


  end
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message actually does state pretty clearly what is the problem: Calling

`render layout: false`

inside `UserManagementController#new` *implicitly* expects a template `new` to be present in either

`app/views/user_management/new.erb` or

`app/views/application/new.erb`

Read [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for a thorough explanation.